# Easy way to scale up a div and have scale and positioning match a child div?

Tags: javascript, css, web

Is there an easy way to scale up a parent `div` and position a child `div` clicked inside it to the center of the screen?

Initial state:

[image]

After user clicks one of the small circles:

[image]

html:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="circle1" onClick="scaleAndPositionContainer()">
</div>

<div class="circle2" onClick="scaleAndPositionContainer()">
</div>

<div class="circle3" onClick="scaleAndPositionContainer()">
</div>

<div class="circle4" onClick="scaleAndPositionContainer()">
</div>

<div class="circle5" onClick="scaleAndPositionContainer()">
</div>

<div class="circle6" onClick="scaleAndPositionContainer()">
</div>

<div class="circle7" onClick="scaleAndPositionContainer()">
</div>

<div class="circle8" onClick="scaleAndPositionContainer()">
</div>

<div class="circle9" onClick="scaleAndPositionContainer()">
</div>

<div class="circle10" onClick="scaleAndPositionContainer()">
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {


transform: scale(1);

-moz-transition: all .25s cubic-bezier(0, 1.8, 1, 1.8);
-webkit-transition: all .25s cubic-bezier(0, 1.8, 1, 1.8);
-o-transition: all .25s cubic-bezier(0, 1.8, 1, 1.8);
-ms-transition: all .25s cubic-bezier(0, 1.8, 1, 1.8);
transition: all .25s cubic-bezier(0, 1.8, 1, 1.8);

}

.circle1 {
width:50px;
height:50px;
position:absolute;
left:5%;
bottom:10%;
border-radius:50%;
background-color:#ffffff;
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}

.circle2 {

width:40px;
height:40px;
position:absolute;
left:10%;
top:10%;
border-radius:50%;
background-color:#ffffff;
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}

.circle3 {

width:50px;
height:50px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
border-radius:50%;
background-color:#ffffff;
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}

.circle4 {

width:30px;
height:30px;
position:absolute;
left:25%;
top:60%;
border-radius:50%;
background-color:#ffffff;
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}

.circle5 {

width:70px;
height:70px;
position:absolute;
left:40%;
top:40%;
border-radius:50%;
background-color:#ffffff;
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}

.circle6 {

width:55px;
height:55px;
position:absolute;
left:80%;
top:30%;
border-radius:50%;
background-color:#ffffff;
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}

.circle7 {

width:50px;
height:50px;
position:absolute;
right:40%;
top:20%;
border-radius:50%;
background-color:#ffffff;
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}

.circle8 {

width:30px;
height:30px;
position:absolute;
left:70%;
top:70%;
border-radius:50%;
background-color:#ffffff;
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}

.circle9 {

width:70px;
height:70px;
position:absolute;
left:40%;
bottom:20%;
border-radius:50%;
background-color:#ffffff;
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}

.circle10 {

width:50px;
height:50px;
position:absolute;
right:20%;
top:20%;
border-radius:50%;
background-color:#ffffff;
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}
```

Script:

```
<script>

function scaleAndPositionContainer(){

console.log("clicked");

$('.container').css({
        '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(10)',
        '-moz-transform'    : 'scale(10)',
        '-ms-transform'     : 'scale(10)',
        '-o-transform'      : 'scale(10)',
        'transform'         : 'scale(10)'
});

//Shift Position

}

}

</script>
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Our format requires that you've made an effort and then post a more specific question.

Comment: I would separate the content and the circles, each circle has an attribute to know wich content div it is related to. When you click a circle you scale it and move it to the center using top, left, width and height and then you fade in the corresponding content. I fear that using scale(10) won't lead to nice results.

Comment: So I get scaling and moving each circle to the center based on a click, but how do I get the other circles to scale and move in conjuncture with that clicked circle? Is there some kind of relative position/scale I need to program for each?

Comment: I may not be explaining it right either. The result would be similar to navigating an iOS home screen, where you click on a folder and it essentially zooms in to folder you clicked.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you something to work on. For centering, I'd like to know what should happen when a circle in a corner is clicked, as there isn't going to be enough space to have it centered. I also made it so that it zooms out if clicked outside the circles.

```js
function scaleUp(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $('.container').css('transform', 'scale(5)');

    $('.container').css('transform-origin', e.clientX + "px " + e.clientY + "px");

}

function scaleDown(e) {
    $('.container').css('transform', 'scale(1)');
}
```

```css
html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    background-color: black;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}

.circle1 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left:5%;
    bottom:10%;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}

.circle2 {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    top:10%;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}

.circle3 {

    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}

.circle4 {

    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    left:25%;
    top:60%;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}

.circle5 {

    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    position:absolute;
    left:40%;
    top:40%;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}

.circle6 {

    width:55px;
    height:55px;
    position:absolute;
    left:80%;
    top:30%;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}

.circle7 {

    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    right:40%;
    top:20%;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}

.circle8 {

    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    left:70%;
    top:70%;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}

.circle9 {

    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    position:absolute;
    left:40%;
    bottom:20%;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}

.circle10 {

    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    right:20%;
    top:20%;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container" onclick="scaleDown(event)">
        <div class="circle1" onClick="scaleUp(event)"></div>
        <div class="circle2" onClick="scaleUp(event)"></div>
        <div class="circle3" onClick="scaleUp(event)"></div>
        <div class="circle4" onClick="scaleUp(event)"></div>
        <div class="circle5" onClick="scaleUp(event)"></div>
        <div class="circle6" onClick="scaleUp(event)"></div>
        <div class="circle7" onClick="scaleUp(event)"></div>
        <div class="circle8" onClick="scaleUp(event)"></div>
        <div class="circle9" onClick="scaleUp(event)"></div>
        <div class="circle10" onClick="scaleUp(event)"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This result helped me with other problem. Thank you